# Неточный перевод в очереди проверок

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, очередь-проверок, спасибо

Мне кажется перевод в очереди проверок не совсем точный.

Сейчас так:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос почему "комментарий", а не ответ?

В англоязычной версии глянуть не могу, но сообщение такое:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть: "Пожалуйста, не добавляйте "Спасибо" **как ответ**. (дословно если)

Мне кажется нужно сделать: **"Это ответ типа "Спасибо"**.

Comment: В английской версии всегда можно посмотреть [текст в традусёре](https://ru.traducir.win/string/5237). И как можно видеть там нет слова "ответ". Поэтому искажать перевод не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Можно заменить на:

> Это **сообщение** типа "Спасибо"

Answer (score 0):

Вполне сочетается с предыдущим пунктом "это не ответ, а комментарий". Т. е. имеется в виду, что "спасибо", которому место в комментарии (что вообще-то тоже спорно), размещено в виде ответа.

Да и вообще под "комментарием" можно понимать реакцию, а не вид сообщения на сайте.

В общем, я считаю, что менять не надо.

Answer (score 0):

А вообще, можно поменять, чтобы там ничего не говорилось про комментарий или ответ, а именно:

> Это благодарность

Answer (score -1):

Модификация соседнего ответа для удобства голосования:

> Это благодарность, опубликованная в виде ответа